# How to install libsoup 3.0 Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, libsoup

For my rust project  I need to install libsoup 3.0, Ubuntu 22.04 does not want to install it.

Outptut when I build the rust project is failed to run custom build command for `soup3-sys v0.5.0`

I've tried to install

```
sudo apt install libsoup-3.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libsoup-3.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libsoup-3.0'
```

Comment: [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com)

Comment: The package is called [`libsoup-3.0-0`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libsoup-3.0-0).